cordova - google maps not rendering on android 13
I'm trying to update my Ionic app to Cordova Android 13 but its facing some problem.
Google Maps is not being rendered and gives no error or crashes the app.
It gets a black screen and only shows background = #FFF in console coming from js_CordovaGoogleMaps-for-android_ios.js file at line 802.
For browser and iOS its working fine and doesn't show that console.log message.
Here is some info from my package.json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.0.0-beta.27",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "colors": "1.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.1",
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@chacabuk/cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "github:TSFArg/cordova-plugin-googlemaps",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "cordova-android": "^13.0.0",
    "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-androidx-build": "^1.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^16.0.0-cli",
  },
  ...
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.12.0",
        "LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": ""
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GPS_REQUIRED": "true"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
        "ANDROID_FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "21.2.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release": {
        "PLAY-SERVICES-MAPS": "17.0.0"
      },
      "barcodescanner-ec": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {},
    },
  }
  ...
}

Am I missing something?
How can I get some debug information on that?
thanks

There seems to be a PR: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/pull/2872

Time to update that app. your behind 10 versions of angular, YIKES!
